# Incoherencia de accesibilidad c#

Tags: c#, poo

Tengo la siguiente que clase que me marca error en la segunda palabra Dirección del metodo virtual:

```
public class Profesor {
        public Profesor() {
        }
        public Profesor(int id, string nombre, string ape1, string ape2) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.ape1 = ape1;
            this.ape2 = ape2;
        }
        private int id;
        public virtual int Id {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private String nombre;
        public virtual string Nombre {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        private String ape1;
        public virtual string Ape1 {
            get { return ape1; }
            set { ape1 = value; }
        }
        private String ape2;
        public virtual string Ape2 {
            get { return ape2; }
            set { ape2 = value; }
        }
        private Direccion direccion;
        public virtual Direccion Direccion {
            get { return direccion; }
            set { direccion = value; }
        }

    }
```

El error dice **Incoherencia de accesibilidad: El tipo de propiedad 'Direccion' es menos accesible que la propiedad 'Profesor.Dirección'** ¿Como puedo solucionarlo? Esta es la clase Dirección:

```
class Direccion {
        public Direccion() {
        }
        public Direccion(int id,String calle, int numero,String poblacion, String provincia) {
            this.id = id;
            this.calle = calle;
            this.numero = numero;
            this.poblacion = poblacion;
            this.provincia = provincia;
        }
        private int id;
        public virtual int Id {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        private String calle;
        public virtual String Calle {
            get { return calle; }
            set { calle = value; }
        }
        private int numero;
        public virtual int Numero {
            get { return numero; }
            set { numero = value; }
        }
        private String poblacion;
        public virtual String Poblacion {
            get { return poblacion; }
            set { poblacion = value; }
        }
        private String provincia;
        public virtual String Provincia {
            get { return provincia; }
            set { provincia =value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu propiedad `Direccion` tiene el mismo nombre que la clase `Direccion`...

Comment: Si lo sé, es el mismo nombre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probá con hacer `public` la clase `Direccion`

`public class Direccion { ....`

Comment: Gracias, era eso, no me había dado cuenta que le faltaba el public

Comment: Muy útil hasta la fecha.

Answer (score 3):

En `c#` existen estos niveles de acceso(`internal`,`private`,`protected` o `public`) y se infieren dependiendo del contexto, en el caso que no sean especificados, en caso de las clases que se crean directamente debajo de un namespace, por defecto son internal, lo cual quiere decir que solo sera accesible por las clases del mismo ensamblado, este es el caso de `Direccion`, pero `Profesor` es una clase pública, lo cual indica que puede ser utilizado por cualquier ensamblado, al declarar la propiedad `Direccion` pública estás indicando que puede ser accedida por cualquier ensamblando pero el tipo no lo es.

En [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173121.aspx) sitio encontras mas detalles de los niveles de acceso.